# How do I add variable number of months to a date in Ruby (avoid using loop)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there something similar to the code below in Ruby where **X** stands for the number of months to add to today's date but is coming from a variable

```rb
Time.zone.today + X.month ## X comes from a variable
```

**Preferably without using a loop as 'm' can be large number in the example below**

```rb
def add_months_to_today(m)
  number_of_months_to_add = m.to_i
  return_date = Time.zone.today
  if m.to_i > 0
    (1..number_of_months_to_add).each do |i|
      return_date = return_date + 1.month
    end     
  end

  return_date
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine:

```
x = 4
Time.zone.today + x.month
#=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
```

[`month`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Integer.html#method-i-month) is a method defined on `Integer`. It doesn't matter if the integer is given as a literal or as a variable. The receiver just has to be an `Integer`.

---

Instead of `Time.zone.today` you could also call [`Date.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current):

```
Date.current + 4.month  #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
```

Rails also adds a variety of other methods to [`Date`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html): (also via [`DateAndTime::Calculations`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html))

```
Date.current.advance(months: 4) #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
Date.current.months_since(4)    #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
4.months.since(Date.current)    #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
```

The above also work for instances of `Time`:

```
Time.current.advance(months: 4) #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:11:52 CEST +02:00
Time.current.months_since(4)    #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:11:52 CEST +02:00
4.months.since                  #=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:11:52 CEST +02:00
```

When only dealing with dates, Ruby's built-in [`>>`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) or [`next_month`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month) might be used as well:

```
Date.current >> 4
#=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019

Date.current.next_month(4)
#=> Sun, 29 Sep 2019
```

Note that you can use `4` and `x` interchangeably in all of the above examples.